# Passing a String Array List from an adapter and getting a null result

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-arrayadapter

First of All, I will tell you my englist is very bad, And new to code.

So, Please be patient and kind to me :)

I have pass `String` and `StringArraylist` throug `Intent`.

And I getting problem to pass `StringArraylist`.

**arrayAdapter**

```
    userId = data.get ( getAdapterPosition () ).getUserId ();
    name = data.get ( getAdapterPosition () ).getName ();
    ImageUrl  = data.get ( getAdapterPosition () ).getImageUrl ();

    Intent intent = new Intent (mContext, DisplayActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle ();

    bundle.putString ("userId", userId);
    bundle.putString ("name", name);
    bundle.putStringArrayList ( "ImageUrl ", (ArrayList<String>) ImageUrl );

    intent.putExtras ( bundle );

    Toast.makeText ( mContext, "userId = " + userId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
    Toast.makeText ( mContext, "name = " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
    for (int i = 0; i < ImageUrl.size (); i++) {
        Toast.makeText ( mContext, "Url " + (i+1) + " = " + ImageUrl.get ( i ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
    } // Checked all result and everything is fine.

    intent.addFlags ( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK );
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

> All result of `userId` `name` and `ImageUrl` get correctly.

**DisplayActivity**

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    assert bundle != null;

    String userId = bundle.getString ( "userId" );
    String name = bundle.getString("name");
    ArrayList<String>ImageUrl = bundle.getStringArrayList ("ImageUrl");

    Toast.makeText ( DisplayActivity.this, "userId is = " + userId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
    Toast.makeText ( DisplayActivity.this, "Name is = " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
    if (ImageUrl == null) {
        Toast.makeText ( DisplayActivity.this, "ImageUrl = null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < ImageUrl.size (); i++) {
            Toast.makeText ( DisplayActivity.this, "Url " + (i+1) + " = " + ImageUrl.get ( i ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        }
    }
```

> String value of `userId` and `name` is passed, And display correctly.
>
> Just only `ImageUrl` is get null result.

I know this is stupid question and already have "so many" topic.

But, I have try myself

Example :

**arrayAdapter**

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra ( "ImageUrl ", (ArrayList<String>) ImageUrl );
```

**DisplayActivity**

```
ArrayList<String> ImageUrl = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra ("ImageUrl");
```

Don't have any fit answer and get same result.

Plese, help me.

I can't find the way out. ;(

Comment: what does getImageUrl() in your adapter return? A string or a list of string?

Comment: 'list of string' for sure.

Comment: public List<String> getImageUrl() {
        return ImageUrl;
    }

Comment: My new lesson. Key name : "ImageUrl " != "ImageUrl"

Answer (score 0):

This is not a  right type to pass bundle using intent

Please use this to pass your data in other activity

**If using activity then use
To Send data**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtras("key",value)
```

**In another activity to get passed data**

```
String s = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
```

**you get your value in `s` variable** **and change variable type as per your requirement**

**If you are using Fragment then pass data like this**

```
   bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString ("userId", userId);
    bundle.putString ("name", name);
    bundle.putStringArrayList ( "ImageUrl ", (ArrayList<String>) ImageUrl );
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

and to get your passed data in another fragment use

```
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        String userId = bundle.getString ( "userId" );
        String name = bundle.getString("name");
```

**Your Code**

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle ();
    bundle.putString ("userId", userId);
    bundle.putString ("name", name);
    bundle.putStringArrayList ( "ImageUrl ", (ArrayList<String>) ImageUrl );

    intent.putExtras (bundle);
```

And To Get data you are using

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    assert bundle != null;

    String userId = bundle.getString ( "userId" );
    String name = bundle.getString("name");
```

Comment: Thank you, but I send from Adapter to Activity. And I already try from you recomment and get null for StringArrayList. (No problem from string)

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize your ArrayList into a String and pass it to the next activity as a string value.

```
 // creating output stream variables
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

        try {
            // for writing or saving binary data
            fos = new FileOutputStream("SaveArrayList.ser");

            // converting java-object to binary-format 
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            // writing or saving ArrayList values to stream
            oos.writeObject(yourarraylist);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
            fnfex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ioex) {
            ioex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Later in the second activity you can de-serialize the String into an ArrayList again.

```
List<String> yournewarraylist= null;

        try {
            // reading binary data
            fis = new FileInputStream("SaveArrayList.ser");

            // converting binary-data to java-object
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            // reading object's value and casting ArrayList<String>
            leadersOfHistory = (ArrayList<String>) ois.readObject();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
            fnfex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ioex) {
            ioex.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ccex) {
            ccex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For put use this

```
bundle.putStringArrayList("ImageUrl", new ArrayList<>(ImageUrl));
```

For get data use this

```
bundle.getStringArrayList("ImageUrl")
```

Comment: That is my first try and get null result from StringArrayList.